# Type of iPhone/iPad/iOS application - modal view, tabbed, other?

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios

I'm making my first iOS application to be run specifically on an iPad as part of my final year project at University.

I've been experimenting with the different types of applications and I'm stuck wondering what would be the best type for my application - the application is to quote for a service offered by a local business, they have 12 different types of quotes, and would like a main screen to select which type of quote calculator is shown.

I'm just wondering if this would be a job for modal views or if I should use a tabbed application, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 12 different types of quotes, I'd recommend using a 'navigation' style application. On the main page, setup a UITableView that has buttons linking to each type of quote. Then, present them using the navigation controller.